# On proving that integration can be used to get big-O complexity

Tags: integration, number-theory, functions, summation, asymptotics

In big O notation we have that for all $x \geq x_0$:

$f(x) \in O(g(x))$ if there exists a positive real $c$ where $|f(x)| \leq cg(x)$

My question has to do with using integrals to approximate big O.

For example what is the big-O of:

$$T(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k$$

We can compute that directly and the result is $n(n+1)/2$ so it's $O(n^2)$.

But for something like the following $S(n)$ we don't have a clean way to get a closed form of the sum:

$$S(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{k}$$

But we can approximate it with an integral

$$\int \sqrt{k}~dk = (2/3)k^{3/2} + c_0$$

and here we say that $S(n) \in O(n^{3/2})$.

We could have done the same thing with $T(n)$, too:

$$\int k~dk = (1/2)k^2 + c_0$$

Which suggests $O(n^2)$ as it did earlier.

But what's the proof that we can always get the big-O by taking an integral, rather than computing the exact sum?

More specifically:

1. How do I know that it is even valid to use an integral rather than the explicit sum?
2. How do I know the result when using an integral will have the same big-O as the result when performing the sum?

Comment: On def'n and notation : $F(x)\in O(G(x))$ as $x\to \infty$ iff  $\exists c>0\;\exists r \;;(x>r\implies |F(x)|<c|G(x)|).$  It is not necessary that  $|F(x)|<c|G(x)| $  for all $  x. $  Also it should be specified what the limit of $x$  is. For example $x\in O(\sin x)$ as $x\to 0$  means $\exists c>0\; \exists r>0\;(|x|<r\implies |x|<c|\sin x|. $

Comment: For all $x \geq x_0$, which can be anything (e.g. some large number)

Comment: I don't understand that at all.   What has that have to do with the def'n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the sum of $\sum_i c_i$ as a collection of rectangles, with the $i$th rectangle having base $[i, i+1]$ on the $x$-axis and height $c_i$. Compare the area of this sum of rectangles with the integral of the associated function from $0$ to $n+1$. By sliding the rectangles left or right by one unit, you can typically show either upper or lower bounds.

For this to work, the following are sufficient:

- The numbers $c_i$ are monotone increasing or decreasing (which is typically true), or at least have this property for all $i > N$ for some fixed $N$.
- The function whose values are the $c_i$ (in your examples, $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ are monotone, so that for $i < x < i+1$, you have $c_i < f(x) < c_{i+1}$. (Or the less-thans might be greater-thans....but the key thing is that it's one or the other for all $i$.)

Comment: @KaliMa. Note that we often only need a crude estimate . For example if  $a,b>0$ and $aS(n)<\int_1^n f(x)\;da <bS(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$ then $\int_1^nf(x)\;dx=O(S(n))$ as $ n\to \infty,$  and vice-versa,